# Is it a good approach to combining denormalizr with reselect?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux, reselect

I'm using [reselect](https://github.com/reactjs/reselect) with [denormalizr](https://github.com/gpbl/denormalizr) to avoid to denormalize on each change, but I don't really know if this is really improving something.

```
import { createSelector } from 'reselect'
import { denormalize } from 'denormalizr'
import { challenge as schema } from './challenge.schema'

const getState = (state) => state

export const getChallenge = createSelector(getState, ({ entities, challenge }) => {
  return denormalize(entities.challenges[challenge.item], entities, schema)
})

export const getChallenges = createSelector(getState, ({ entities, challenge }) => {
  return challenge.items.map((id) => denormalize(entities.challenges[id], entities, schema))
})
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Rule is usually to not optimise your code until you actual need it. If you don't know if you need to optimise, you may be in a case of premature optimisation.

In this case, if it slows down your app you should probably do it. Problem is often to know if this is actually slowing down your app or not. 
You can use a monitor tool or simply comment/uncomment the code and trigger a state change and see if you app stays responsive without reselect.

Answer (score 1):

Your entities map is modified on each change (either for the current object or some completely different object). Reselecting the output of denornalize doesn't improve your performance because it returns a new object on each call. The reselector is called when any of the entities have changed, so the result is still a call every time.